# Найти value в генерируемом html коде

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php, html

Требуется найти всё значение value,html код:

```
<input type="hidden" name="ctl00_ToolkitScriptManager1_HiddenField" id="ctl00_ToolkitScriptManager1_HiddenField" value=";;AjaxControlToolkit, Version=4.1.40412.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e:en-US:acfc7575-cdee-46af-964f-5d85d9cdcf92:de1feab2:f9cec9bc:8ad18101:f2c8e708:720a52bf:589eaa30:698129cf:e148b24b">
```

в конечном итоге $result должен содержать = ";;AjaxControlToolkit..."
Пробовал через regex

```
$re = '/<input type="hidden" name="ctl00_ToolkitScriptManager1_HiddenField" 
id="ctl00_ToolkitScriptManager1_HiddenField" value="(.+?[^\\])">/';
preg_match($re, $result, $matches)[1];
$HiddenField = $matches[1];
```

Answer (score 2):

Найти всё, что в value, если значение value гарантировано оформлено в двойные кавычки и внутри значения нет двойных кавычек

```
$re = '/value="([^\"]+)">/';
```

Но я бы воспользовался чтением HTML как XML и поиском через XPath - это хоть и медленнее, но надёжнее.

Answer (score 0):

Не надо "через regex" пробовать. Есть немало нормальных способов, даже для PHP. Например:

```
include 'simple_html_dom.php';
$dom = str_get_html($html);
foreach($dom->find('input[name=ctl00_ToolkitScriptManager1_HiddenField]') as $i)
  echo $i->value;
```